Putting a login Authentication using Azure features in React Application
I am currently working on a calendar application which needs a login/user authentication. I tried doing it using azure, but due to my lack of expertise in Azure I found myself lost in multiple tutorials. I need the solution of this one. Any help or leads would be really helpful.
Here is how my application looks like.
Index.js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ContextWrapper>
      <App />
    </ContextWrapper>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

App.js
return (
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element = {
            <React.Fragment>
              <div className="overall">
                <CalendarHeader />
                <div className="main-content-area">
                  <Sidebar />
                  <Month month={currentMonth} />
                  <EventModal />
                </div>
              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
            }>
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/addEvents" element={<UpdateEventsForms />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/editdeletedata" element={<EditAndDelete />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/adminPage" element={<AdminPage />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
  );

Header.js
<div>
 <button className="button-calendar-today">Sign-In</button>
 <button className="button-calendar-today" onClick={() => navigate("/adminPage")}>Admin 
 Login</button>
</div> 

And how I want is like when the user is not logged-in then don't want to display admin page instead I would like to show sign-in button. But when the user is logged-in I want to display the admin page not the sign-in button.
Moreover, when clicked on Admin login that will take the user to the Admin Page (<AdminPage />) which is user in my react-router above in App.js

I tried the following React.js code for login/user authentication with Azure Active Directory.
Code :
AdminPage.js :
import React from 'react';
const AdminPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Admin Page</h1>
      {/* Add your admin page content here */}
    </div>
  );
};
export default AdminPage;

Home.js :
import React from 'react';
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
      {/* Add your home page content here */}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Home;

SignInButton.js :
import React from 'react';
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';
const SignInButton = () => {
  const { instance } = useMsal();
  const handleLogin = () => {
    instance.loginPopup();
  };
  return <button onClick={handleLogin}>Sign In</button>;
};
export default SignInButton;

msalConfig.js :
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
      clientId: '<client_ID>',
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>',
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
    },
  }; 

App.js :
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MsalProvider, AuthenticatedTemplate, UnauthenticatedTemplate, useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { msalConfig } from './msalConfig';
import AdminPage from './components/AdminPage';
import Home from './components/Home';
import SignInButton from './components/SignInButton';

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

function App() {
  const { accounts } = useMsal();
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
     const account = accounts[0];
    setUser(account);
  }, [accounts]);

  return (
    <Router>
      <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/adminPage" element={<AdminPage />} />
        </Routes>
        <AuthenticatedTemplate>
          <Navigate to="/adminPage" />
        </AuthenticatedTemplate>
        <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
          <SignInButton />
        </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
      </MsalProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;

I added the output URL below in the Azure AD app's Authentication as a Single-page application.
http://localhost:3000


Output :
The React application below ran successfully.

I received the output below in the browser. Then, I clicked on Sign In and selected my credentials for signing in as shown below.

I successfully signed in and got the Admin Page as below.


Hey, @Dasari I got another doubt, at admin page say there is a button called 'Access' but I don't want to show that to all the users rather just few selected users only. Those who don't have access to that page just an error message saying "You don't have admin access." Then what changes shall I make?

@Pixel
To achieve this, you can conditionally render the "Access" button on the Admin Page based on the user's permissions, displaying an error message for users without admin access.
